# Как сделать на кнопке текст подчёркнутым?

Tags: css

Есть кнопка `<input type="submit">`. Как можно сделать текст на
кнопке подчёркнутым пунктиром? Вот собственно,
что хочется получить.[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  <style type="text/css">
   A.dot {
    text-decoration: none; /* Убираем подчеркивание */
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #000080; /* Добавляем свою линию */
   }
</style>
<body>
<a href="#" class="dot">отправить заявку`</a>`
```

Comment: Ну для ссылки я знаю. Вопрос был про текст на кнопке.

Comment: а чем вам <a> не угодило как содержимое кнопки ? http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/s9bJg/

Comment: @Виктор Павлов, ссылка как раз и обрамляется рамкой. А то, что зеленым - это может быть все что угодно. Например, блок или элемент списка. http://jsfiddle.net/KzqgX/ - как пример, кривенько немного, зато показательно.

Comment: Кнопка <input name="" type="submit" value="ОТПРАВИТЬ ЗАЯВКУ" class="send"> отправляет данные формы методом POST. И как я в VALUE вставлю ХТМЛ-тэги? Или может я что-то неправильно понял?

Comment: Ну, как вариант, хотя и не самый лучший, можно сделать тип не submit, а image, а саму кнопку нарисовать в фотошопе.

Comment: Вот так еще можно - http://jsfiddle.net/r7Ae2/1/

Comment: Тоже не вариант. Нужно, чтобы вся зелёная область была кликабельна.

Comment: вы наверное не знаете, но каждый button в form работает как submit.
http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/s9bJg/

Comment: @Виктор Павлов, для таких же, просто это альтернатива. Этот тег как раз и предназначен для решения подобных задач. http://htmlbook.ru/html/button

Comment: А какой вариант лучше использовать? button или с label?

Comment: а вот используя :active, мы превращаем кнопу в кнопку http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/s9bJg/5/

Answer (score -2):

From StackOverflow:

```
<form id="form-id">  
  <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('form-id').submit();"> submit </a>  
</form>
```

ну а ссылку оформляете абсолютно как хотите (размер, фон, текст внутри)

Comment: Яваскрипт как-то не хочется для формы использовать. Ну если ничего не придумаю, воспользуюсь вашим советом.

Comment: ужаснейшее решение. один `onclick=""` чего стоит....

Comment: А почему решение ужасное? Я на форумах почитал, используют люди.

Comment: люди много что используют, во первых js, там где он не нужен, во вторых, onclick="" в третьих... да просто document.getElementById('form-id') когда элемент **уже** внутри формы... это идиотизм.